# SSDM : Error in rasters stack and SSDM's model prediction

Tags: raster, r

I'm actually working on Environemental data to build an SDM model.
I faced some problems during data processing.
 I extracted my environnemtal  from ENVIREM database, res=30 arc-sec.
 I checked my rasters before stacking them, there was 0 NA's.
When I stack them I get a lot of NA values as shown below:

```
AnPETM_1  topwetM_1 ArdindexM_1  PETSeasM_1 PETWettQuartM_1
Min.    2.669464e+01     885.400       6.17       63.69    1682.990           25.81
1st Qu. 4.269421e+01    1333.732      10.54       78.82    3789.467           61.24
Median  5.209351e+01    1464.990      12.32       92.96    4974.755           88.65
3rd Qu. 6.036992e+01    1640.975      13.51       97.47    5840.647          115.53
Max.    8.304529e+01    2012.200      15.17       98.90    7386.350          213.46
NA's    2.594705e+06 2594248.000 2594248.00  2594248.00 2594248.000
```

Is there any solution to keep real values in my rasterstack during prediction process.

2/ I used my raster stack in SSDM for single species distribution.
I got this;

```
 ***Warning messages:
1: In min(pred[which(obs == 1)]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(pred[which(obs == 1)]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In cor(predicted.values, o.predicted.values) : l'écart type est nulle
4: In cor(predicted.values, o.predicted.values) : l'écart type est nulle
5: In cor(predicted.values, o.predicted.values) : l'écart type est nulle
6: In cor(predicted.values, o.predicted.values) : l'écart type est nulle
7: In cor(predicted.values, o.predicted.values) : l'écart type est nulle***
```

Comment: Without your data I don't think we can help. If the rasters you stacked don't align perfectly then maybe the NAs are where rasters don't overlap and the system is filling out with NAs. Hard to tell without some description of your raster layers.